# Как сравнить значение со списком (массивом) с помощью SQL?

Tags: sql, массивы, триггер

- Есть 3 массива заранее известных чисел:
  `[1, 5, 9, 12, 14, 16, 19, 23, 27, 30, 32, 34]
   [3, 6, 8, 10, 13, 17, 21, 24, 25, 29, 33, 36]
   [2, 4, 7, 11, 15, 18, 20, 22, 26, 28, 31, 35]`
- Необходимо определить к какому из этих массивов относится добавленное число
- И получить число, предположим от 1 до 3 (порядковый номер или название линии)

---

> Например, в таблицу_1 заносится запись, после добавления с помощью
>   триггера я получаю число, которое было добавлено и хочу сделать запись
>   в таблицу_2, где мне необходимо знать название или порядковый номер
>   `line_#`.
>
> Для наглядности, можно взять число 8, оно относится к линии №2
>   Могу ли я реализовать данное действие только с помощью sql?

*Заранее благодарю за помощь!*

Comment: Может case и in? `case
 when n in (1, 2, 3) then 1
 when n in (4, 5, 6) then 2
 when n in (7, 8, 9) then 3
 else 0
end`

Comment: В общем случае SQL не знает о таком типе данных, как "массив". Если необходимо именно SQL-решение, и "массив" должен браться из некоей таблицы, а не хардкодиться - укажите точно DBMS, включая версию, опубликуйте структуры хранения, примеры исходных данных, и желаемый для таких данных ответ (оптимум - создайте fiddle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если массив заранее известен и не предполагается, что он может измениться в будущем, то вариант с case, предложенный justcvb будет оптимален.

Если в будущем возможно изменение/расширение этих массивов, то создать дополнительную таблицу, содержащую два столбца: номер массива и значение, с индексом по последнему.

Comment: *вариант с case, предложенный justcvb будет оптимален* Зависит от СУБД. Например, для MySQL эта фраза, увы, неверна.